# Registering multiple Mesos Slaves from different computers

Tags: apache, master-slave, mesos

I am trying to set up Mesos with 1 master and 3 slaves running on several computers all on the same switch. Each computer is a 4-socket dual core machine running `Ubuntu 13.04`. I have installed mesos, and can create one master and one slave when ssh'd into the same computer using the local IP. However, when I try to create a slave on a second computer connected via the master's public IP, the slave appears to register.  I get the following message, indicating that it has connected to the master:

```
I0627 16:02:42.431401 10059 slave.cpp:2873] Current usage 0.81%. Max allowed age: 6.243193692985590days)
```

However, the Mesos tracking website does not recognize the second slave.

Additionally, when frameworks are started when ssh'd into a different computer (than the master), the framework stalls out at:

```
I0627 15:52:44.045642 10254 sched.cpp:230] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication.
```

The task also fails to appear on the mesos tracking website. However, frameworks that are launched from the same computer as the master using the local IP do execute normally. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you received the answer on the mesos's user list, but just in case here is the answer.

Both the framework (and slaves) and master need to be able to talk to each other. IOW, if one of the end points uses a private IP (e.g., 127.0.0.1) then it wouldn't work. If you want the master/slave to use a public ip you can use --ip flag. For the framework, you can set LIBPROCESS_IP in the environment.